# Why wouldn't other receptacles work after I changed a receptacle?

Tags: electrical

One of my outlets was getting very hot so I took it apart, cleaned it because it was very very dirty and changed the outlets. It stopped getting hot and the tester said it was correct but now the other outlets do not work at all. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the outlet was part of a chain of outlets - so there would be at least 2 cables of 3 wires each (hot, neutral and ground).

All of the hots need to be connected together and to the outlet.  Same for the neutral and ground. Often this is done by using the screws on the outlet itself - connecting BOTH hot wires to the two screws for hot.  Only connect one wire per screw.

If you connected it exactly the same way as it was before it should work.  Did you break off the little tabs between the sets of screws?  Were they broken off on the old one?  Make sure they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Either you disconnected something unintentionally,  or you shorted something and blew a fuse/popped the circuit breaker. Without seeing exactly what you did, and preferably how you did it,  I don't think there's much more we can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

If the replaced outlet is working, then it is because the other outlets were chained onto the replaced one, but they are not reconnected.  Turn off the circuit, pull the outlet out and make sure all the connections are good.  Besides the ground, there are two pairs of wires:  one pair provides power and the other goes off to the next outlet or switch.